# Clearance authentication only for admin dashboards

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, clearance

I have a rails app which is publicly available but has an admin dashboard that should be accessed only by registered users.

I'm using Thoughtbot Administrate for the dashboard part and I'm trying to implement dashboard authentication with Clearance.

My app does not have any authentication for the public part, so I moved the line `include Clearance::Controller` from `ApplicationController` to `Admin::ApplicationController` and put the sign in/logout buttons in a navigation bar in my dashboard, however, when I click on sign in button, the app shows me an authentication form for my app, not for the dashboard part (I can tell because the styles used are different for both), so my question is, is there a way to have clearance installed only for the admin part, like having it installed only for the admin namespaces?

Clearance part of `rake routes` is:

```
         passwords  POST   /passwords(.:format)                     clearance/passwords#create
      new_password  GET    /passwords/new(.:format)                 clearance/passwords#new
           session  POST   /session(.:format)                       clearance/sessions#create
     user_password  POST   /users/:user_id/password(.:format)       clearance/passwords#create
edit_user_password  GET    /users/:user_id/password/edit(.:format)  clearance/passwords#edit
                    PATCH  /users/:user_id/password(.:format)       clearance/passwords#update
                    PUT    /users/:user_id/password(.:format)       clearance/passwords#update
             users  POST   /users(.:format)                         clearance/users#create
           sign_in  GET    /sign_in(.:format)                       clearance/sessions#new
          sign_out  DELETE /sign_out(.:format)                      clearance/sessions#destroy
           sign_up  GET    /sign_up(.:format)                       clearance/users#new
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is your output from `rake routes` and what does your sign in link look like in your layout?

Comment: `rake routes` output is quite long, but I edited the question to show the clearance part, as for the sign in link, it's this one: `link_to 'Sign in', sign_in_path`, because there's no `admin_sign_in_path`.

Comment: Are you saying you just want the sign_in form to use a different layout?

Comment: Hi Derek, sorry for the late response, it's been a busy week.

Right now, the authentication is not working, so I have to figure out what I did wrong because it was ok before.

In any case, I think yes, using the same layout that Administrate uses for the sign_in form would be ok :)

Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the only issue is that the Clearance controllers are using your application layout rather than your admin layout. You can override this and it is [documented in the README](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance#layouts).

```
Clearance::PasswordsController.layout 'my_passwords_layout'
Clearance::SessionsController.layout 'my_sessions_layout'
Clearance::UsersController.layout 'my_admin_layout'
```

Whatever you would like. If you want to impact all of the clearance views, I think you could do:

```
Clearance::BaseController.layout 'my_admin_layout'
```